# Adding a download button using sdk gxp opengeosuite

Tags: boundless-suite

I'm using GeoExt to make an  Open Geo suite SDK viewer, I have added many tools but I need also to add a  "download" button -connected with geoserver- in order to download each layer in different formats as csv, WFS....
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out https://github.com/bartvde/sdk-export-app it should give you some inspiration on how to achieve this.